# How make (PHP Tools for VS Code) not make (emmet.excludeLanguages) to PHP language

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, visual-studio-code

When I use (PHP Tools for VS Code) it make:

```
 "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
        "markdown",
        "php"
    ],
```

in **settings.json**
this make me not can use emmet for generate HTML tags in PHP files.
I want to stop this functionality.

Comment: remove "php" ? from the there.

Comment: every time i reopen vscode it make it again @xNoJustice

Answer (score 0):

This is hardcoded by PHP Tools to disable emmet in PHP files since it causes the code completion to be shown twice. I would suggest creating an issue with details on https://github.com/DEVSENSE/phptools-docs/issues